# Cannot understand how node.js lambda function returns value after a mysql query

Tags: node.js, promise, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

First of all, I apologize if the header of my question is misleading.

I am creating an API using the AWS API gateway and the integration type is a lambda function.

So basically in my frontend (React) there is a textarea where user can input search values, each value on a new line. I take the input from that textarea, split into an array, convert to JSON and pass it my API endpoint.

My API endpoint passed that value to a lambda function. The objective of a lambda function is to take that JSON value (array), loop through it, search for it on the database and return the matched rows.

The code below should explain what I am trying to do.

```
    exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        var queryResult=[];
        var searchbyArray = (event.searchby);
        var len = searchbyArray.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             var sql ="SELECT * FROM aa_customer_device WHERE id LIKE '%"+searchbyArray[i]+"%'";
             con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
             if (err) throw err;
             queryResult.push(result);
         });
         var formattedJson = JSON.stringify({finalResult:queryResult});
         return formattedJson;
    }
};
```

Think of the code above as a pseudo-code as i have tried different ways of achieving the desired result.

For example without using async and using something like:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) { //code goes here }
```

which results in

> Time out error

I am fairly new to node.js (the world of async function and promises). Can someone help in the right direction on what I am doing wrong and what is the correct way?

The only thing right in that code is that the array 'searchbyArray' contains the correct values which need to be searched.

I read the AWS documentation of AWS lambda function using node js and still couldn't figure out what the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that NodeJS MySQL library uses callbacks, not promises. You'll need to wrap each query with a promise so you can properly `await` the query, or be able to use something like `Promise.all(`). You could use the `util.promisify()` function for that. Alternatively, switch to the promise-based [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) for querying MySQL in NodeJS.

I also suggest adding lots of logging to your function so you can see exactly how far it's getting, where it's timing out, and what the variable contents and any error messages are.

Another alternative would be to use Python for writing your Lambda function instead of NodeJS which doesn't present these asynchronous complexities.

Comment: From what I can see the problem here is that my con.query() function takes time to return the result and since it's an async function the code moves to the next block which is a return statement. Since the function is returned well before con.query() returns a result, everything just dies i guess. I simply can't work my way around (super noob using nodejs, just been a few days). I can of course use python but the main idea behing using nodejs was to actually learn something new on this project so i dont want to take the PYTHON path just yet.

Comment: @Ashish you are correct what the problem is. As I explained in my answer you need to convert those MySQL calls to promises somehow (I gave a few methods in my answer) and then `await` those promises.